# how to implement SQLite in Android application ?

Tags: android

I am new to android application development. help me how to store the data using SQLite concept. I have 2 EditText fiels those are Name and Mobile number and one button "Save"
in my main.xml and now,I am trying to store that Name and Mobile NUmber when the "Save" button clicked...

Help me out with an simple example

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 16):

Use the below links. Surely this will help. These links will easily understandable for beginners.

[Sqlite for beginners in Android](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/AndroidSQLite.aspx)

[Sqlite Tutorial 2](http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7742)

[Sqlite Tutu 1](http://www.xoriant.com/blog/mobile-application-development/android-sqlite-database.html)

Comment: one more good sqlite android tutorial to start http://www.quicktips.in/basic-android-sqlite-database-exampletutorial/